# Why swift dictionary crashed on concurrency?

Tags: swift, thread-safety

Here is sample code:

```
var dict = [Int: Int]()
for i in 0...100 {
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        dict[i] = i
    }
}
```

I know swift collection is not thread safe. But what confuse me is why it crashed. The key and value is an `Int` which is value type.

[Xcode Crash Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vq6VI.png)

Comment: `I know swift collection is not thread safe` <- This.

Comment: I guess `.global()` is concurrent queue. That means two or more operation are mutating `dict` at a same time.

Comment: So, why concurrency write cause crash? What happened in memory?

Answer (score 0):

Collections in Swift are not thread-safe.

It's crashing because `.global()` is a concurrent queue, which means that multiple operations are mutating `dict` at the same time.

It is unsafe to let one thread modify the dictionary while another is reading or writing it.